# Why is my loop speeding up and slowing down randomly?

Tags: java, performance

Not quite sure the correct way to ask this question, but my loop sometimes slows down while it is printing the variable, then speeds back up to the original speed it was going at. I know that System.out.println does slow down the loop time, but is it the main problem what is effecting the program, because it does this randomly, not just at one point in time, as I have re-run the loop multiple times. I don't think it is necessarily a code problem, but here is what I have so far:

```
public class Earth
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Person[] people = new Person[50000];
        for (int i = 0; i < people.length; i++)
        {
            people[i] = new Person();
            people[i].initializeHuman();
            System.out.println("Person[" + i + "] initialized");
        }
    }
}
```

Person in this case is an extension of multiple classes, and people is the object that is created by main which contains the extension of the multiple classes.

The slowing down happens randomly at different instances of the iteration of the loop (each time I run it), and I was wondering if anyone had previous experience on this issue and what the problem is. The main reason I'm asking this question is because I had the same issue before on a school computer, but printing a list of prime numbers (it would randomly slow down than speed back up to normal speed.)

Here is initializeHuman, which pretty much just sets values in different classes I created:

```
public void initializeHuman()
{
    setTimeUntilTired(57600);
    setCurrentTimeUntilTired(0);
    setTimeAlive(9460);
    setTimeToLive(252288);
    setHeight(68);
    setWeight(170);
    setAthleticism(4);
    setIsDressed(true);
}
```

Comment: What does this method `initializeHuman` do ?

Comment: I'll post it at bottom.

Comment: Well if those set method is just setting values on you class attributes without any computing what you are experiencing is a processor priority managed by the Operatiom System.

Comment: There's probably a better way to initialize your class. But there's nothing here that suggests "random" slowdowns.

Comment: My first guess was that garbage collection takes place, but I don't see here any objects to collect

Comment: Okay, it's probably just what Taelsin stated, even though I'm not really running anything besides program on computer. Thanks though.

Comment: @Riley Carney Even if you are not actively running anything other than your IDE your OS will always be using resources on one thing or another, even if it seems it is just idling. That being said, it shouldn't be giving you much of a perceivable slowdown as you described.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are a lot of possible reasons why this would happen. My best guess from the info you provided is that some other process or processes on your machine needed resources that caused the CPU usage to spike while you were running the program.